# PHP Sessions & Cookies Getting Deleted?

Tags: php, cookies

On both Chrome & Firefox, this lasts for about an hour then the session cookie, and other cookies set by javascript disappear. I didn't even close the browser.

```
session_set_cookie_params(946080000); // 30 years
session_start();
$_SESSION['login']=true;
```

Gone. The session cookies are gone. I assume its not a browser thing because it disappears on both Chrome & Firefox. I didn't test on IE.

Is this normal behavior... I'm certain it is not being unset somewhere.

Sorry, I know I haven't given much info, but that's because there is not much info to give. It should work and it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong, if possible change php.ini to reflect the coockie duration you want to apply. Reading from php.net manual:

> "Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this
>   function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to
>   call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before
>   session_start() is called.
>
> This function updates the runtime ini values of the corresponding PHP
>   ini configuration keys which can be retrieved with the ini_get()."

This means you need to call it EVERYTIME in all your php file before you do a session_start(). A blog post that may have the solution: http://blog.centresource.com/2006/05/23/php-session-lifetime-an-adventure/

To change the value in PHP ini use following line:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime "946080000"
```

Anyway its better to use a coockie, sessions aren't used for a long lifespan, rather use cookies instead.

Comment: There is a cookie on there too, which also mysteriously disappears, also set to 20 or 30 years. And I did make sure that `session_set_cookie_params` is before each `session_start`. I'd rather not change the expiry for all sites, because on some I don't want so long a session.

Comment: @Alasdair Try `setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);` after `session_start()` and remove `session_set_cookie_params(946080000);` I think that the problem is not on the server. just cookies expire.

Comment: @PLB, thanks, though I can see in Chrome that the cookies are set to 30 years with the `session_set_cookie_params`.